# Why is subject-verb inversion necessary in "War kaum einer drunter"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Ach, all die Aufträge, die ich schon für sie erledigt habe. **War** kaum **einer** drunter, der sich für mich gelohnt hätte.

I wonder if these two separate sentences are actually made up of a single sentence in the speaker's mind, as belows?

> Ach, **von all den Aufträgen**, die ich schon für sie erledigt habe, **war** kaum **einer** drunter, der sich für mich gelohnt hätte.

Then, the prepositional phrase placed at the top necessitates the *war* & *einer* inversion, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not an inversion, it's an elision of "es" because of sloppy or colloquial speech, and the word order doesn't change if parts are left out:

> **Es** war kaum einer darunter, der ...

Though the subject usually comes after the verb when the first position of the sentence is already taken by something else, I recommend to think of the rule as "verb always second in a main clause" and not as some kind of inversion.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to say "Es gibt kaum einen drunter, der"?

Comment: Yes, that's also possible, though it's "d**a**runter". And "es gab kaum einen darunter" would be more natural, because this is about jobs offered in the past.